# One to many users based on a club

Tags: c#, ef-core-3.1

I have a site with clubs and members and am just checking this is the right way to link its members.

I club can have many members and those members can be users or admins.

```
public  class Club    {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Guid? TeannatId { get; set; }
    public Guid? UserId { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }       
    public string? Description { get; set; }     
    public List<ApplicationUser>? Members { get; set; }
}
```

Should I also store my asp net identity roles in here I mean to get the relationship or just keep them as is.

```
 public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser   {
    public enum UserTypeEnum
    {
        Guest=0,
        User=1,
        Author=2,
        AddonOwner=3,
        GroupOwner=5,
        SuperAdmin=199
    }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public bool isOnline { get; set; }
    public int UserType { get; set; }
    public Guid TennantId { get; set;}
    public Guid? ClubId { get; set; }
    public List<Badges> Badges { get; set; }


}
```

I presume I need to set the relation back to the user somehow here?

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)  {
  base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);         
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend you don't use enum as your user type. It is better to create a special table for it :

```
public UserType
    {
      public int Id {get; set;}
      public string Name {get; set;}
    }
```

and your ApplicationUser class will be like this

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser  
 {
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public bool isOnline { get; set; }
    public int UserTypeId { get; set; }
    public virtual UserType UserType { get; set; }
    public Guid TennantId { get; set;}
    public virtual Tenant Tennant { get; set;}
    public Guid? ClubId { get; set; }
    public virtual Club Club { get; set; }
    public List<Badges> Badges { get; set; }
}
```

And remove ? from Members

```
public virtual List<ApplicationUser> Members { get; set; }
```

since a List is null by default.

Comment: I have roles created but i was using the user types to define more application specific roles for memeber's tier prob the wording is confusing do i need to use the include function then when am calling clubs to ensure users gets populated

Comment: Yes, if you want  Members of the Club  instance to be populated immediately you have to use context.Clubs.Include(m=> m.Members)

Comment: But sometime a club may have no members only the admin or would i treat him as a member

Comment: Yes, I would do this way. It is always better to use the same code for everybody and don't  have a different code for each user type. I guess each club has an admin at least. And if it has only one member this member is admin. But if you don' t like to include admin in members you can use this code -  .Include( i=>i.Members.Where ( x=> x.UserType.Name !=" SuperAdmin") )

Comment: How would you advise those where I would want to make a user within a club and admin or a memeber role then as you say the super users would do all the full admin rights over all clubs I under stand that bit just not the first part of making members admins or members mangers

Comment: Kinda of like roles within roles i guess

Comment: You can assign any kind of roles - admin of one club or admin of all clubs. Maybe you have to remain  a usetype to  a userrole as well

Comment: So keep my user type enum u think as a sub member type